# Slow Framerate Capturing Video from Raspicam

Tags: c++, opencv, video, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to use a Raspberry Pi camera to record a video. I want to use openCV to do the recording, because when I have this working I will do some more processing.

I'm using the raspicam/raspicam_cv library from [here](http://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40). I am able to open the camera and read into a cv::Mat, and create a video, but the frame rate is between 1-2 Hz.

My code is here:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <raspicam/raspicam_cv.h>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std; 

int main ( int argc,char **argv ) {

    time_t timer_begin,timer_end;
    raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv Camera;
    cv::Mat image;
    int nCount=100;

    cout<<"Opening Camera..."<<endl;
    if (!Camera.open()) {cerr<<"Error opening the camera"<<endl;return -1;}

    cout<<"Capturing "<<nCount<<" frames ...."<<endl;
    time ( &timer_begin );

    cv::VideoWriter writer("Avideo.avi", CV_FOURCC('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'), 30, cv::Size(1280,960), true);

 for ( int i=0; i<nCount; i++ ) {
    char name[32] = {0};
        Camera.grab();
        Camera.retrieve ( image);
    writer.write(image);    
    }
    cout<<"Stop camera..."<<endl;
    Camera.release();

    time ( &timer_end ); /* get current time; same as: timer = time(NULL)  */
    double secondsElapsed = difftime ( timer_end,timer_begin );
    cout<< secondsElapsed<<" seconds for "<< nCount<<"  frames : FPS = "<<  ( float ) ( ( float ) ( nCount ) /secondsElapsed ) <<endl;

}
```

When I run the program `raspivid` I can see videos which seem to run at 30 Hz which is what I would like to achieve.

I can also only get this code to work using size 1280x960 for some reason.

If anyone could give me some tips that would be great.

Comment: Please start by identifying which line causes the slow down. For example, I would start by commenting out the videowriter `writer.write(image);` and see how this affects the speed.

Comment: Commenting out `writer.write(image)` makes the video exactly 10 Hz

Comment: Please provide link for raspivid's cpp code to compare.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/raspicam/files/raspicam-0.1.3.zip/download

Comment: There is no rapisvid file/project in the srouce code. Did you mean raspicam_cv_test?

Comment: Oops, sorry, my fault: https://github.com/raspberrypi/userland/tree/master/host_applications/linux/apps/raspicam

Comment: Have you had any success recording video with openCV with decent frame rate? I am currently stuck with the same problem:(

Comment: I decided to change from a Raspberry Pi to an Odroid C2. Using the Odroid C2 I can record at 15 Hz.

Answer (score 1):

The default size of `raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv` is 1280*960,you can use `get` to get:

```
double RaspiCam_Cv::get ( int propId );
```

for example:

```
Camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
Camera.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
```

If you want other size,you can use `set` to set:

```
bool RaspiCam_Cv::set ( int propId, double value );
```

for example:

```
Camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640);
Camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480);
```

The other properties can get/set include:

```
 * CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,
 * CV_CAP_PROP_FORMAT: CV_8UC1 or CV_8UC3
 * CV_CAP_PROP_BRIGHTNESS: [0,100]
 * CV_CAP_PROP_CONTRAST: [0,100]
 * CV_CAP_PROP_SATURATION: [0,100]
 * CV_CAP_PROP_GAIN: (iso): [0,100]
 * CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE: -1 auto. [1,100] shutter speed from 0 to 33ms
 * CV_CAP_PROP_WHITE_BALANCE_RED_V : [1,100] -1 auto whitebalance
 * CV_CAP_PROP_WHITE_BALANCE_BLUE_U : [1,100] -1 auto whitebalance
 * CV_CAP_PROP_MODE : [1,7] 0 auto mode
```

PS:The FPS and size of `cv::VideoWriter` must be same with `raspicam::RaspiCam_Cv`,otherwise,`cv::VideoWriter` will never work.